# CSS TR height not working when using percentage and table height is in px

Tags: css, html-table

I have set my `<table>` `width` in pixels, and I want to have table with two `<tr>` and they have two `<td>`.

My CSS is:

```
table {
width:100%;
height:300px;
}

.ruutu {
width:50%;
height:50%;
}

.ruutu img {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

`<td>` `width` should always be 50% of `<tr>`'s `width`. And its `height` should be 50% `<tr>`'s `height`.

But only `width` is working, and `height` is not.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ugv3G/7/

Comment: These percentages refer to the percentage of the TABLE, not the TABLE ROW. A TR takes on the height of its biggest TD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad idea with table cells and height.

Add a div inside the td and give that a height. Inside img will now know of the height

http://jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/Ugv3G/13/ (first row first cell)